# Material UI Icon and D3

Tags: d3.js, material-ui

All of our Icons are based on MaterialUI icons `@material-ui/icons/ICON_NAME`.

Would like to use the Left & Right Chevron in a D3 graph.

Is there a way to export the SVG out of Material UI and append it to the D3 graph?

Tried Append and HTML on the D3 graph and neither worked.

```
...
import ChevronLeft from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft";


svgChart
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "button left-button")
  .attr("transform", "translate("(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  .html(() => <ChevronLeft />)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use a React element directly in D3.

Howerer you can copy the path from [`ChevronLeft.js`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui-icons/src/ChevronLeft.js) on material-ui's GitHub and add it to you `path` in D3. You see that the code is `<path d="M15.41 7.41L14 6l-6 6 6 6 1.41-1.41L10.83 12z" />`.

```js
const svgChart = d3.select('#chart');
const margin = {
  left: 20, 
  top: 20,
};

svgChart
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'button left-button')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`)
  .append('path')
  // Add the path here
  .attr('d', 'M15.41 7.41L14 6l-6 6 6 6 1.41-1.41L10.83 12z');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg id="chart" heigh="200" width="200"></svg>
```

Maybe there is a better way to retrieve the path from the JSX.

Comment: That is what I thought.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is a better way, you can get the string component and add it to your `g` element.

```
// imports
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import ChevronLeft from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft";

// code
const iconHtml = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<ChevronLeft />);
svgChart
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "button left-button")
  .attr("transform", "translate("(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  .html(iconHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was building on @thibautg solution, but I had some issues changing the size of the icon. Came up with this solution that worked. All you need to do is to change the path which you can find on their API docs.

```
    svg.current
        .append('g')
        .attr(
            'transform',
            `translate(${outerRadius/ 5},${-outerRadius / 5})`
        )
        .append('svg')
        .attr('viewBox', '0 0 100 100')
        .attr('width', `${width.current / 5}px`)
        .attr('height', `${width.current / 5}px`)
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', 'm4 12 1.41 1.41L11 7.83V20h2V7.83l5.58 5.59L20 12l-8-8-8 8z')
        .style('fill', 'green')
        .style('stroke-width', 5);
```